# Aligning equations both left and right in same display

Tags: math-mode, align, flalign

I am looking for an elegant way to achieve the following display, in which consecutive lines in math-mode have opposite justifications:

[image: pic]

I was able to do so using the following hack

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + a_4 x^4 +a_5 x^5 + a_6 x^6 \leq f(x) + g(x)+ h(x)    &&
\end{flalign*}
\vspace{-0.4in}
\begin{flalign*}
&& \leq 
b_0 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2 + b_3 x^3 + b_4 x^4 +b_5 x^5 + b_6 x^6,
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Can this be achieved with a single align-type environment?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It strongly depends on your definition of elegant. Please describe more what you want to achieve.

Comment: multline* (amsmath) sort of does that, but it doesn't go quite all the way to the edge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{multlined}[\linewidth]
a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + a_4 x^4 +a_5 x^5 + a_6 x^6 \leq f(x) + g(x)+ h(x)\\
%
\leq b_0 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2 + b_3 x^3 + b_4 x^4 +b_5 x^5 + b_6 x^6,
\end{multlined}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

Is this what you after?

Answer (score 0):

You could overlap the lines.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
\mathrlap{a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + a_4 x^4 +a_5 x^5 + a_6 x^6 \leq f(x) + g(x)+ h(x)}&&\\
&&\mathllap{\leq 
b_0 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2 + b_3 x^3 + b_4 x^4 +b_5 x^5 + b_6 x^6,}
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```